# How can I alias an inherited overloaded method?

Tags: python-3.x, methods, operator-overloading, alias, typing

How can I alias an inherited overloaded method and preserve the method input + output signature?

The method must have a new name in the class that inherits from the base class.

For example:

```
class BaseApi(api_client.Api):
    @typing.overload
    def _redirection(
        self,
        server_index: typing.Optional[int] = None,
        stream: bool = False,
        timeout: typing.Optional[typing.Union[int, typing.Tuple]] = None,
        skip_deserialization: typing_extensions.Literal[False] = ...,
    ) -> typing.Union[
        response_3xx.ResponseFor3XX.response_cls,
        response_303.ResponseFor303.response_cls,
    ]: ...

    @typing.overload
    def _redirection(
        self,
        skip_deserialization: typing_extensions.Literal[True],
        server_index: typing.Optional[int] = None,
        stream: bool = False,
        timeout: typing.Optional[typing.Union[int, typing.Tuple]] = None,
    ) -> api_client.ApiResponseWithoutDeserialization: ...

    @typing.overload
    def _redirection(
        self,
        server_index: typing.Optional[int] = None,
        stream: bool = False,
        timeout: typing.Optional[typing.Union[int, typing.Tuple]] = None,
        skip_deserialization: bool = ...,
    ) -> typing.Union[
        response_3xx.ResponseFor3XX.response_cls,
        response_303.ResponseFor303.response_cls,
        api_client.ApiResponseWithoutDeserialization,
    ]: ...

    def _redirection(
        self,
        server_index: typing.Optional[int] = None,
        stream: bool = False,
        timeout: typing.Optional[typing.Union[int, typing.Tuple]] = None,
        skip_deserialization: bool = False,
    ):
        # implementation

class ApiForGet(BaseApi):
    # this class is used by api classes that refer to endpoints by path and http method names

    def get(
        self,
        server_index: typing.Optional[int] = None,
        stream: bool = False,
        timeout: typing.Optional[typing.Union[int, typing.Tuple]] = None,
        skip_deserialization: bool = False,
    ):
        return self._redirection(
            server_index=server_index,
            stream=stream,
            timeout=timeout,
            skip_deserialization=skip_deserialization
        )

class Redirection(BaseApi):
    # this class is used by api classes that refer to endpoints with operationId.snakeCase fn names

    def redirection(
        self,
        server_index: typing.Optional[int] = None,
        stream: bool = False,
        timeout: typing.Optional[typing.Union[int, typing.Tuple]] = None,
        skip_deserialization: bool = False,
    ):
        return self._redirection(
            server_index=server_index,
            stream=stream,
            timeout=timeout,
            skip_deserialization=skip_deserialization
        )
```

When I call
`res = BaseApi._redirection(skip_deserialization=True)` I get `ApiResponseWithoutDeserialiation`
But when I use:
`res = ApiForGet._redirection(skip_deserialization=True)` I get `ApiResponseFor3XX | ApiResponseFor3XX | ApiResponseWithoutDeserialiation`

Note: I am using vscode

The options that I can think of are:

- write the overload in ApiForGet + Redirection but this duplicates them 2X
- use some kind of decorator magic that renames the methods and overloaded methods

How can I do this?
Why are my typed inputs not being passed through to the deeper call site?

These work, are there better ways?

```
class ApiForGet(BaseApi):
    # this class is used by api classes that refer to endpoints by path and http method names

    get = BaseApi._redirection


class ApiForGet(BaseApi):
    pass

ApiForGet.get = ApiForGet._redirection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These work:

```
class ApiForGet(BaseApi):
    # this class is used by api classes that refer to endpoints by path and http method names

    get = BaseApi._redirection


class ApiForGet(BaseApi):
    pass

ApiForGet.get = ApiForGet._redirection
```